# How to create a widget consisting of different shapes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to create a widget in flutter and that widget must contain different shapes like rectangle, triangle, circle etc. Each of these shapes must also be a widget. Can anyone please tell me how to do it? I am new to flutter.

[image]

Comment: Use ClipPath widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html

Comment: see https://blog.logrocket.com/drawing-shapes-in-flutter-with-custompaint-and-shape-maker/

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom paint to draw every thing you want,

Refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4-XLVRCRpA&t=411s) tutorial

Example [github code](https://github.com/JohannesMilke/custom_paint_ii_example)